# Missing template after copying rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, missing-template

I copyed/pasted my rails project from work computer to personal computer on an Ubuntu Virtual Box, and I have an error while I try to access a page : "Missing Template".

Does anyone have an idea ?

(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Can you post the entire error?

Comment: Exactly how did you "copy/paste" it over?

Comment: I copy/past what were inside my folder, and thats all. I created a new project on my computer and past it in.
Here's my error : 

ActionView::MissingTemplate at /products

Missing template products/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/benjamin/workspace/Projet_ERP_Rails/app/views" * "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/kaminari-0.15.1/app/views"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In views folder, rails can't find `index.html.erb` file in `/products` folder.
Make sure you have index file there.
If it is not so paste your directory structure here

It should be here

```
/home/benjamin/workspace/Projet_ERP_Rails/app/views/products/index.html.erb
```

If it is not there, then create one.